# What's the difference between Protobuf ToByteArray and WriteDelimitedTo function in C#?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, memorystream

So I'm new to C# and I need to communicate with server (implemented in go) using protobuf + websocket. My initial implementation looks like this:

```
var command = new Command
            {
                //some fields
            }.ToByteArray();
_websocketClient.SendAsync(command);
```

where `_websocketClient` is using [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) client.

However, on server side I cannot unmarshall the bytes from request and got error

> proto: Command: illegal tag 0 (wire type 1)

This is the error from proto generated code. It looks like the bytes I send is somehow invalid. I then switched to this implementation

```
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
command.WriteDelimitedTo(ms);
_websocketClient.SendAsync(ms.GetBuffer());
```

and everything is working fine now. So it looks like this is caused by the way that struct is serialized. But I didn't find any documentation explaining what `writeDelimitedTo` actually does and how it is different from `ToByteArray()`.

Can someone explain to me what's the difference here that caused my first implementation to fail? Much appreciated and many thanks!

Comment: What is `Command`? Something from the protobuf library?

Comment: @Sweeper `Command` is just struct defined in my proto file. Like this `message Command {//some member fields}`

Comment: Your working version: is wrong - GetBuffer() returns the **oversized** backing buffer, including trailing garbage (usually zeros). I suspect trailing zeros are somehow making this work, probably by terminating the reader. Can I see the server reader code here? Btw the correct MemoryStream code would be: `if (!ms.TryGetBuffer(out var buffer)) buffer = new(ms.ToArray());` then `blah.SendAsync(buffer.Array!, buffer.Offset, buffer.Count);` (or `blah.SendAsync(buffer.AsMemory());` or similar).

Comment: Or simpler: to test, use ToArray() instead of GetBuffer(). And in particular, I'd be looking at what the **bytes** are from the two; if you get the (correctly sized) bytes from both approaches: are they the same? if not, can you show the hex for each? Tip: BitConverter.ToString(array) and BitConverter.ToString(array, offset, count) are lazy but useful ways of getting hex strings (for debug purposes l, usually). My hunch is that the bytes will be the same, and the real difference here is the trailing zeros, which suggests that the real problem here is: "framing".

Comment: And if the real problem is "framing", the question becomes: what framing does the existing server expect? (And why, since web-sockets has framing already)

Comment: @MarcGravell You are right about my working version is wrong. I encountered another problem when I was sending a request with no content. I.e `Command{//no member initialized}`. And after switching to `ms.ToArray()`, the problem went away. I can share the hex for `toByteArray()` ,`GetBuffer()` and `ToArray()` below

Comment: `GetBuffer()` and `ToArray()` has the same hex on struct with members. However, `ToByteArray()` 's hex is missing the first four bytes. The missing bytes are `FD-04`. I cannot share the whole hex here as they are too long. lmk if you need them and I can prob use a google doc or sth.

Comment: And for empty struct it's different. `GetBuffer()` returns a bunch of `00`s, which should be the trailing zeros you are talking about. `ToArray()` returns only `00` and `ToByteArray()` returns nothing. And I just checked the server side, the only thing that lib does to frame is to ignore `EOF` errors, which shouldn't be the cause of those issues.

Comment: BTW, for the struct with member variables, there's no trailing zeros in hex from `GetBuffer()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've dug into the source code, and the answer here is that indeed they write different things:

- `ToByteArray` writes the [regular protobuf payload of the message, via `WriteTo`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/34517b6456e8015584ba0b54237adc3d8479c38d/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/MessageExtensions.cs#L117)
- `WriteDelimitedTo` does the same payload, [but *with an additional length prefix*](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/34517b6456e8015584ba0b54237adc3d8479c38d/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/MessageExtensions.cs#L146)

The purpose of the latter *in the general case* is because protobuf is not a self-terminating message format, which means: it doesn't know when any single message stops - you just keep reading until you reach an EOF. This is problematic if you are writing multiple messages to a single stream, for example a socket server - hence you need "framing" to break this into a series of logical payloads, and `WriteDelimitedTo` is a simple mechanism for providing this "framing".

In the case of web-sockets, web-sockets *itself* provides framing, so *in theory* you don't actually need to prefixed form, however when it comes to serialization, the more important question is:

> What does the other end expect?

So ultimately: figure out which of those two alternative layouts is expected by the Go server, and *use that* - even if it means it is partly redundant in a framed protocol such as web-sockets. If you use the wrong alternative layout, it will be misinterpreted by the deserializer, leading to this kind of problem.

Technically `ToByteArray` is the more *semantically correct* (in a framed context), but: being "correct" doesn't help us if the receiver expects the prefixed form.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I re-checked the lib code and it indeed uses length to deserialize. It will first read the length then deserialize accordingly. I suppose it's doing so because it's also supporting transport other than websocket, like sockjs. So it will have to do "framing" by itself. BTW, I now switched to using `ToArray()`, is there any drawbacks compared to the idiomatic way that you suggested?  Again, many thanks for your help!

Comment: "I suppose it's doing so because it's also supporting transport other than websocket, like sockjs" - yup, that makes perfect sense